# How to use hashtable add datagridview data?

Tags: c#

How to use hashtable add the data of datagridview? Then save them as a file. Load the file while the form running.
Please help me! Thanks! I don't know which methods best except LINQ.
The following is my codes:

```
 Hashtable tmpData = new Hashtable();
    public frmInputScore()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitEmployees();

        if (dgvScoreList.DataSource == null)
        {
            dgvScoreList.DataSource = new DataTable();
        }

        if (!File.Exists("tmpData.dat")) return;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("tmpData.dat", FileMode.Open);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        tmpData = (Hashtable)bf.Deserialize(fs);
        fs.Close();

        tbEmployeeId.Text = tmpData["EmployeeId"].ToString();
        cmbEmployeeName.SelectedValue = tmpData["EmployeeId"];
        dtpGradeDate.Value =Convert.ToDateTime(tmpData["GradeDate"]);
        cbTopMost.Checked =Convert.ToBoolean(tmpData["TopMost"]);
        dgvScoreList.DataSource = tmpData["DataSource"];
    }
    private void SaveConfig()
    {
        tmpData.Clear();
        tmpData.Add("EmployeeId", cmbEmployeeName.SelectedValue);
        tmpData.Add("GradeDate", dtpGradeDate.Value);
        tmpData.Add("TopMost", cbTopMost.CheckState);
        tmpData.Add("DataSource", dt);
        FileStream fs = new FileStream("tmpData.dat", FileMode.Create);
        BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
        bf.Serialize(fs, tmpData);
        fs.Close();
    }
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void dgvScoreList_UserAddedRow(object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        dgvScoreList.CurrentRow.Cells["EmployeeName"].Value = cmbEmployeeName.Text;
        dgvScoreList.CurrentRow.Cells["EmployeeId"].Value = cmbEmployeeName.SelectedValue;
        dgvScoreList.CurrentRow.Cells["GradeDate"].Value = dtpGradeDate.Value;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvScoreList.Rows)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(row); 
        }

        SaveConfig();
    }
```